# Why are some characters being replaced with boxed question marks on High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, font, text

I'm noticing characters being replaced by boxed question marks. It's happening most often for emoji and accented characters, I think, and I've seen it in Safari, Chrome and the system dictionary.

[image]

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.1 (17B48) on a mid-2014 MBP. No software updates pending.

Comment: Try Font Book > File > Restore Standard Fonts

Answer (score 1):

The font does not contain a glyph for that particular IPA symbol, and the font substitution algorithm failed to catch it.  [Report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) it as a bug.